# Save file dialog confirmation

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, dialog

i got struck at making a save file dialog box. I got everything done, but I want to show a dialog box when I try to save file which is already existing, with options to override,cancel or no. When the user click no, I want the saveFodlerDialog to show up again and iterate the process. But I dont know how to implement it.

I am pasting relevant code below:

```
private void New_Project(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var saveFolderDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dlgResult = saveFolderDlg.ShowDialog();

        if (dlgResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            saveFolderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
            saveFolderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            string projectPath = saveFolderDlg.SelectedPath;
            string prjFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(projectPath);
            string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(projectPath, prjFileName);

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newPath+".rnd"))
            {
                CreateNewProejct(projectPath);//works fine
            }
            else
            {
                string msgBoxTxt = "Project already exists, Override?";
                MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel;
                string caption = "New porject";
                MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(msgBoxTxt,caption, button, icon);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case MessageBoxResult.No:
                        //what to do here to restart the process of saving project
                        break;                           
                    case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                        break;
                    case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                        CreateNewProejct(projectPath);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could recursively call the NewProject method again.

```
private void NewProject()
{
    var saveFolderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    DialogResult dlgResult = saveFolderDlg.ShowDialog();

    if (dlgResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {

        saveFolderDlg.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
        saveFolderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        string projectPath = saveFolderDlg.SelectedPath;
        string prjFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(projectPath);
        string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(projectPath, prjFileName);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newPath + ".rnd"))
        {
            CreateNewProejct(projectPath);//works fine
        }
        else
        {
            string msgBoxTxt = "Project already exists, Override?";
            MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel;
            string caption = "New porject";
            MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(msgBoxTxt, caption, button, icon);

            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.No:
                    NewProject();
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                    CreateNewProejct(projectPath);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Btw: there are some typos in your code --> Proejct :)

Comment: You should generate a new function so that it can cleanly be called from anywhere, not only with some sender and routedEventArgs. Additionally, I would add an extra parameter to set the path for saving. If this parameter is empty, the path should be the desktop, otherwise, open the given path. This way, the user will get the previously chosen folder, much appreciated by all your users ;)

Comment: well, i was unfocused i guess. thanks @BobClaerhout . i will keep in mind.

Comment: yep, i changed the signature of the method and haven't pointed it out.